# sort by name in api

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to sort this image gallery by name, but I really don’t know how to do that?

gallery html

```html
<div>
  <div id="result"></div>
</div>
```

gallery js

```js
const container = document.getElementById('result');

function getData() {
  fetch('https://randomuser.me/api/?results=30')
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((results) => output(results));
}

function output(results) {
  const htmlData = results.results
    .map((result) =>
      `
    <div>
        <img src="${result.picture.large}">
        <div>${result.name.first}</div>
    </div>
    `
    ).join('');

  container.innerHTML += htmlData;
}

getData();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So use sort on your array

```
results.results
  .sort((a, b) => a.name.first.localeCompare(b.name.first))
  .map(...)
```

```js
const container = document.getElementById('result');

function getData() {
  fetch('https://randomuser.me/api/?results=30')
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((results) => output(results));
}

function output(results) {
  const htmlData = results.results
    .sort((a, b) => a.name.first.localeCompare(b.name.first))
    .map((result) =>
      `
    <div>
        <img src="${result.picture.large}">
        <div>${result.name.first}</div>
    </div>
    `
    ).join('');

  container.innerHTML += htmlData;
}

getData();
```

```html
<div>
  <div id="result"></div>
</div>
```